# Can Login Details be Updated for Multiple Linked Tables in MS Access at The Same Time?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to unravel a 15yr old MS Access mess.  I have a MS Access 2007 file that has over 600 linked tables, and over 300 queries.  I am trying to see what is still active, what is up to date, what actually works, etc.  The problem is that I have to enter my login info for every single table/query.  Is there a way to update the login info all at once?  Or add a permissions record or something that it will try automatically?
This file is SO bloated and such a mess that it takes 2-3min to open a single thing, so having to do that 900 times is going to take me quite some time.

Comment: What are the linked tables linked to?  What type of security are you dealing with, Access ULS (user-level) security or something from a database server?

Comment: You can try using the Linked Table Manager. [link1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-linked-tables-1d9346d6-953d-4f85-a9ce-4caec2262797) [link2](https://superuser.com/questions/76849/ms-access-2007-link-table-manager)

Comment: @HansUp SQL server via OBDC connection.  SQL database permissions.  The person who created them is no longer with the company and their info is defaulted and has to be changed on every one.

Comment: @Andre I tried there but it wouldn't let me edit anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop tabledefs and querydefs to set the connect string.

```
Public Sub SetConnectString()

    Dim ODBC_String As String
    ' Define variables or constants for this
    ODBC_String = "ODBC;DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=" & myServer & ";DATABASE=" & myDB & ";UID=" & sUid & ";PWD=" & sPwd & ";LANGUAGE=us_english;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=No"

    Dim DB As DAO.Database
    Dim TD As DAO.TableDef
    Dim QD As DAO.QueryDef
    
    Set DB = CurrentDb

    '--- Linked tables ---
    
    DB.TableDefs.Refresh

    For Each TD In DB.TableDefs
        ' Linked?
        If Len(TD.Connect) > 0 Then
            ' From SQL Server?
            If Left(TD.Connect, 5) = "ODBC;" Then

                Debug.Print "Updating " & TD.Name
                TD.Connect = ODBC_String
                TD.RefreshLink
            
            End If
        End If
    Next TD

    DB.TableDefs.Refresh
    
    '--- PassThrough queries ---
    
    DB.QueryDefs.Refresh
    
    ' PassThrough queries have type dbQSQLPassThrough (returns records) or dbQSPTBulk (doesn't)
    For Each QD In DB.QueryDefs
        If QD.type = dbQSQLPassThrough Or QD.type = dbQSPTBulk Then
            
            Debug.Print "Updating " & QD.Name
            QD.Connect = ODBC_String
        
        End If
    Next QD
                
    DB.QueryDefs.Refresh
    
End Sub
```

This function can also be used to switch from dev/test database to production database.